# Deep applications of the Pettis integral?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, integration

In the Notes section of chapter 2 of Diestel and Uhl's Vector Measures they make the comment:

"Presently the Pettis integral has very few applications.  But our prediction is that when (and if) the general Pettis integral is understood it will pay off in deep applications." ( [Google books link](https://books.google.com.mt/books?id=fEKZAwAAQBAJ&q=exploded#v=onepage&q=%22pay%20off%20in%20deep%20applications%22&f=false) )

That was back in $1977$ and when I did a little searching to find out how well that prediction had fared I found little: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral) provides a cursory description and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Pettis_integral) is arguably better but terser.  [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92974/what-is-the-dunford-integral-and-why-is-it-useful) asks why (Dunford-)Pettis integrals are useful, but I would not say it covers deep applications per se.

So: are there deep applications to the Pettis integral, and if so, what are they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Diestel and Uhl commented on this in [Measure theory and its applications](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NTV7CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA148):

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's excellent, thank-you!